# Angular libraries cross-dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, package.json, tsconfig

I am looking for some help with Angular7 libraries.

I have a **project A** in which I have developed two libraries - **library 1** and **library 2**. The second library (**library 2**) has a dependency on the first library (**library 1**). Later, in another project, let's say **project B** I may use **library 2**.

My problem is with specifying that **library 2** has a dependency on **library 1**. Currently, the two libraries are built in a folder **libs/** in the root of the project - which makes **library 2** imports from **library 1** works with and without specifying that it has a dependency on **library 1** in its *package.json* file.

**Library 1** package.json

```
{
  "name": "library-1",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0"
  }
}
```

**Library 2** package.json

```
{
  "name": "library-2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "7.2.0",
    "library-1": "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Also, their build+dev location is specified in the main tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  ...,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "paths": {
      "library-1": ["libs/library-1", "projects/library-1/src/"],
      "library-1/*": ["libs/library-1/*", "projects/library-1/src/*"],
      "library-2": ["libs/library-2", "projects/library-2/src/"],
      "library-2/*": ["libs/library-2/*", "projects/library-2/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way where I can make it explicit that the second library does not compile if the first one is not installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone else is having a similar setup and wants to know what I did.

1.Added the paths for the different libraries which point to the specific public_api.ts in the **root level tsconfig.json**. This allows on the fly compilation when you use the library in the main project.

```
{ 
   ...options,
   "paths": { 
       "library-1": "projects/library-1/src/public_api.ts",
       "library-2": "projects/library-2/src/public_api.ts"
   }
}
```

2.Added peer dependency in **package.json** of library-2 to library-1. This would show a warning if you use library-2 in a project without adding library-1 as a dependency as well.

```
{
    ...options, 
    "peerDependencies": {
         "library-1": "0.1"
     }
}
```

3. Added an extra **tsconfig.build.json** extends the tsconfig.lib.json and overrides the path for library-1 from the root tsconfig to use the compiled code of that library. This would build library-2 with compiled sources and not just mingle it and directly import from library-1.

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.lib.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "library-1": ["dist/libs/library-1"]
    }
  }
}
```

4.Use the following command to build library-2 so the new tsconfig.build.json is used.

```
ng-packagr -p projects/library-2/ng-package.json -c projects/library-2/tsconfig.build.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error we had on  tsconfig.json

```
 "paths": {
      "dxp-lib-commons": [
        "projects/dxp-lib-commons/src/public-api.ts"
      ],
      "dxp-lib-components": [
        "projects/dxp-lib-components/src/public-api.ts"
      ],
      "dxp-lib-services": [
        "projects/dxp-lib-services/src/public-api.ts"
      ]
    },
```

So commons it is the base for the other two, i had pointed to the public-api,ts on develop and use it fast. Yet when we did a build on this, it will crash with   'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

So after looking several posts i discovered that on build it is necesary to point to the dist and compiled commons not the public-api.ts so on components and service i added on the tsconfig.lib.prod.json

```
"paths": {
  "dxp-lib-commons": [
    "dist/dxp-lib-commons"
  ]
}
```

And worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify the first project as a dependency on the second project [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Local first project": "file:../myprojectfolder/myprojectpackagefolder"
    "Git First project": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.mydomain:first-project.git" 
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if it is not there (the dependency) it will still succeed. Maybe that is an intended way of working of the libraries - all libraries in the same project can be imported in one another?